# このコードを coffee script に変換していただきたいです

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

タイトルの通りです。このコードは coffee scriptでどう記述されるのでしょうか。 
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

function MyController($scope) {

  $scope.foo = ""
  $scope.lastSubmitted = ""

  $scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.lastSubmitted = $scope.foo;
  }
}

app.directive('enterSubmit', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

      elem.bind('keydown', function(event) {
        var code = event.keyCode || event.which;

        if (code === 13) {
          if (!event.shiftKey) {
            event.preventDefault();
            scope.$apply(attrs.enterSubmit);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[js2coffee 2.0 — convert JavaScript to CoffeeScript](http://js2.coffee/)

Comment: 問題なく変換することができました。ありがとうございます。